# decreasing the quality of an image under Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, compression, resolution

Greetings,
I am trying to find an easy way to manipulate an image so that I can decrease the quality of it from 8bit to 3bit.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you want to linearly scale it, just divide each pixel value by 255/7 (i.e. if the original image is stored in a matrix I, let the low-res image J = I/(255/7)).

**UPDATED:** Due to a mistake in my scaling constant.

Here's an example:

[image: Results]

Comment: For a maximum `uint8` value of 255, you would get a rounded-off value of 8, which uses 4 bits. To get a range of 0 to 7, you have to divide by (255/7).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an image that is stored as a `uint8` type in MATLAB, then the pixel values will range from 0 to 255. To limit the values to only 3 bits of precision (thus using only the numbers 0 to 7), you can scale the data as in the following example:

```
>> data = uint8([0 23 128 200 255]);  % Create some data of type uint8
>> scaledData = data*(7/255)

scaledData =

    0    1    4    5    7

>> class(scaledData)

ans =

uint8
```

Note that even though the scaled values are limited to the range of 0 to 7, the variable storing them is still a `uint8` data type since this is the smallest MATLAB will go. The unused higher bits are simply 0.

Depending on how you output the scaled image data to a file (if you want to do that), you may be able to reduce the precision of the stored values to less than 8 bits (for example, [PNG files can store 4-bit types](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-742371)).

Answer (score 1):

`int8` is the smallest integer value in Matlab. You could use only 3 out of 8 bits in int8 by shifting to right any value of any pixel in image.

If you have access to **Fixed-Point Toolbox** instead, you can use `numerictype` objects with the simple notation:

```
T = numerictype(s,w)
```

Cit. from Matlab's manual:

> T = numerictype(s,w) creates a
>   numerictype object with Fixed-point:
>   unspecified scaling, Signed property
>   value s, and word length w.