# How can I decrease a picture's brightness levels in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I decrease a picture's brightness levels in MATLAB? For example from 256 (in 8-bit pictures) to 10?

Comment: in other word, I want to reduce bit depth from 24 or 8 to arbitrary bit depth; in matlab

Comment: similar question: [decreasing the quality of an image under Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519027/decreasing-the-quality-of-an-image-under-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the following code, which may accomplish what you're looking for more directly:

```
srcBitDepth = 8;
dstBitDepth = 2;

img = imread('cameraman.tif');
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(img,[]);

img = bitshift(img, dstBitDepth-srcBitDepth);
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(img,[]);
```

Here's the result:

[image: Bit reduction]

Notice the bit reduction from an original 8-bit image to a 2-bit image.

Answer (score 2):

To convert an image from `X` graylevels into an image with `Y` graylevels, you can write

```
modifiedImage = round( double(rawImage)/X * Y);
```

Then you can convert `modifiedImage` to the integer format of your choice, e.g. `uint8`

```
modifiedImage = uint8(modifiedImage);
```