# convert double to 12 bit using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement color combine function from a imaging software called metamorph in matlab.I have three uint16 bit files(R,G and B) .I need to convert them to 12 bit and then combine them into a RGB image.metamorph converts the 16-bit files to 12-bit and then creates the RGB image from the three 12-bit files.my code is as follows.I am not quite sure how to go about converting a 16-bit image file to 12-bit.

```
    C1 = imread('metamorph/R.tif',3);
    C2 = imread('metamorph/G.tif',3);
    C3 = imread('metamorph/B.tif',3);

    R=mat2gray(C1);
    G=mat2gray(C2);
    B=mat2gray(C3);

    rgb1=cat(3,R,G,B);
    imshow(rgb1)
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I will convert the 12-bit images to RGB.

Comment: I am trying to implement color combine function from a imaging software called metamorph in matlab.I have three uint16 bit files(R,G and B) .I need to convert them to 12 bit and then combine them into a RGB image.metamorph converts the 16-bit files to 12-bit and then creates the RGB image from the three 12-bit files.hope this is more clear.

Comment: Note your question has an "edit" link; use it to add your new info to the question to make it more visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I decrease a picture's brightness levels in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661100/how-can-i-decrease-a-pictures-brightness-levels-in-matlab)

Comment: @user970044: as shown in the linked question, use the following to convert from 16bit to 12bit: `rgb12 = bitshift(rgb16,-4);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MATLAB has a data type for 12 bit (which would be one-and-a-half byte per color per pixel). Of course you can scale you double data to fit into a 12 bit integer:

```
rgb12= round(rgb1/max(rgb1(:))*(2^12-1)); %# scale & round image values to 12 bit
```

... but then the real question is what good does that do:

- do you want to export to some 12bit RGB file format? [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) can apparently do 12bit JPEG, but I'm unsure if that is 12 bit per color.
- or do you want to save RAM while in MATLAB? In this case I'm not sure there is a sensible way to do that.